# Cross compile windows 64 bit .exe from linux

Tags: gcc, 64-bit, cross-compiling, x86-64

I know that if I want to compile a 32 bit .exe for windows on Linux I can just install and use the mingw32 package (e.g. apt-get install mingw32) on linux. What if I want to compile a windows .exe that is 64 bit? Is there tools or a method to do this?

Comment: @Hannes de Jager : Can you please tell me how to compile after `apt-get install mingw32` inorder to produce exe? Can you also please try to answer my questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733402/how-to-build-gnu-libiconv-on-for-windows and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731211/windows-build-system-how-to-build-a-project-from-its-source-code-which-doesnt and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709589/looking-for-information-on-porting-linux-apps-to-windows

Comment: i586-mingw32msvc-cc helloworld.c -o helloworld.exe

Comment: and if you want to test it under linux:
wine helloworld.exe
(assuming you have wine installed)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like my answer lies with the [Mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) project which is available for host OSes Linux, Darwin & Windows

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is very old and already has an accepted answer but I will post this answer the way I do it now. It is pretty simple and straightforward and I hope it helps anyone landing here:

To cross-compile windows applications from a Linux machine you just need to install `mingw-w64` C and C++ compiler. On debian based system you just do this:

```bash
sudo apt install -y gcc-mingw-w64 g++-mingw-w64
```

That will install the `gcc` *(the c compiler)* and `g++` *(the c++ compiler)* **for both 64 and 32 bit cross-compilation**

After that, if you need a 64-bit application just do:

```bash
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ hello.c -o hello.exe
```

And if you need a 32-bit application just do:

```bash
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ hello.c -o hello.exe
```

Simple as that!

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to install MinGW from MSYS2. The main advantages are:

- Usually up-to-date MinGW, regardless of what your Linux distribution ships.
- A lot of [prebuilt libraries](https://packages.msys2.org/package/?repo=ucrt64).

Several MinGW flavors are provided: x32 and x64, with different C runtimes, etc.

You can't install MSYS2 on Linux directly, but it's possible with [Quasi-MSYS2](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2).

1. Install Clang (and LLD):

   On Ubuntu:

   ```bash
   wget https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh
   chmod +x llvm.sh
   sudo ./llvm.sh
   rm llvm.sh
   ```

   Clang can cross-compile to Windows using MSYS2 libraries. Alternatively, you can run MSYS2 MinGW in Wine, but it's slower.
2. Install dependencies:

   ```bash
   sudo apt install make wget tar zstd gpg wine
   ```

   Wine is optional.
3. Install Quasi-MSYS2 and any desired MSYS2 packages:

   ```bash
   git clone https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2
   cd quasi-msys2/
   # Optionally, choose MSYS2 flavor, see full list at: https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/
   # echo MINGW64 >msystem.txt
   make install _gcc _gdb
   ```

   Then:
4. `env/shell.sh` opens a shell with the correct environment variables set up.
5. `win-clang++ hello.cpp` invokes Clang with flags for cross-compilation.
6. `./a.exe` runs the resulting app in Wine, if it's installed.

---

Full disclosure: I'm the developer of quasi-msys2.