# looking for information on porting Linux apps to windows

Tags: c, windows, linux, posix, cross-compiling

Today I've encountered a very good book : [UNIX to Linux® Porting: A Comprehensive Reference 
By Alfredo Mendoza, Chakarat Skawratananond, Artis Walker](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131871099)

This reminded me of the thing I always wanted to know. "Porting Linux apps to Windows". I mean  porting **native Linux apps to native Windows** with no platforms involved.

If I can find any good book which explains this topic. I've lot of amazing linux command line tools in mind which needs a windows port.

Please point me to relevant articles/tutorials/books.

PS: please don't tell me to use linux emulation platforms like Cygwin.

Comment: Your question is not very specific. What libraries do you use in linux? Pthreads? Is this a command line app or a GUI?

Comment: @Sam Post: Well, thats why I've asked a very specific question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733402/how-to-build-gnu-libiconv-on-for-windows/2733428#2733428

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSYS & MinGW are two things that are required for porting apps from Linux to Windows.

Alternative way is to use **Cygwin**. But I don't consider it as 100% porting because it adds dependencies of Cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

Well, [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) is possibly an API you're looking for, if you don't want to use emulation platforms. It provides compatibility between Unix and Win32 apps, and implements some of the win32 API. I'm using it myself for compiling the ns-3 simulator which is designed to run on *nix systems and Cygwin. You still need precompiler statements in there to access certain Win32 features where needed, or to modify macro / function names for cross-compatability. For instance, `Sleep(..)` exists but `sleep(..)` doesn't. There is also no `usleep(..)`. I think this API just makes life easier for the application porter without any downsides.