# Compile libiconv-1.13.1 with Visual C++

Tags: windows, visual-c++, iconv

how can I compile libiconv-1.13.1 with Visual C++ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to build gnu `libiconv` on & for windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733402/how-to-build-gnu-libiconv-on-for-windows)